# How to send a HTML file as a table through outlook?

Tags: python, html, email, outlook

I now have an HTML file and I want to send it as a table, not an attachment by using outlook. The code that I found online only sends the file as an attachment. Can anyone give me ideas on how to do it properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `HTMLBody` property of the `MailItem` class to set up the message body.